# How can i send parameters to validators.lang.yml in symfony2 validator engine?

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I want to translate validation messages in symfony2.

```
address:
    - NotBlank: { message: "address.address.not_blank" }
    - Length:
        min: 10
        minMessage: "address.address.min_length"
```

I want to show min or max limit parameter.

```
address.address.min_length: Address must be at least %limit% characters length
```

But this isn't working!

My translation file name is validators.en.yml.

Users getting error message exactly like this. They are not able to see

> %limit%

How can i show them limit parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Length.html) you should use token:

```
{{ limit }}
```

and not

```
%limit%
```

Now, if you want to supply some parameters that are not strictly bound for the `Length` validator you should probably implement your own validator with translator service as an argument. Then it would be just as easy to use it as `Length` inside configuration.

Comment: I just want to use limit parameter. But it's not working :( I tried every possible combinations like {{limit}} but nothing helped.

Comment: It should be like this: {{ limit }}. For getting variable, you must use exact expression like above with spaces.
False: {{limit}}
True: `{{ limit }}`